# How do I recover the administrator or root password on OS X?

Tags: macos, user-account

I received a hand me down white MacBook with 10.4 on it and it automatically logs into a user account that isn't able to change much in the preference pane. How do I recover or change the administrator password?

The original owner told me to try a few passwords, none of which work to get logged in as admin.

Comment: And if you ever want to make sure that no one can reset your password this simply, you can boot your OS X Install Disk and go to Firmware Utility and set a password.

After that, no one will be able to boot from another source without first typing the firmware password.

Comment: Firmware passwords can be reset if you have physical access to the machine, so don't put all your faith in using those to secure your data.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Boot to OS recovery, internet recovery or on older systems, with a Mac OS X DVD, then there's an option to change passwords.

[image: reset]

You can follow an how-to [here](http://osxdaily.com/2010/02/21/reset-a-lost-password-in-mac-os-x/).

Comment: If you are the user (not the administrator) you can just as the Administrator to reset your password. But, if you are the Administrator, then:

Have your DVD installer ready.
Insert the DVD to the tray
Restart and press down the letter ‘C’. It will load the installer DVD
On the first screen, select Installer > Reset Password
Select your account and make up a new password.
Reboot

Answer (score 16):

Getting admin access without the Setup Utility: another option, for the sake of completeness.

1. Boot into single user mode by holding command-S on boot up.
2. Enter `/sbin/mount -wu /` when the prompt appears to mount the filesystem
3. Enter `rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone`
4. Enter `reboot`

At this point, it should run the colorful little setup utility that ran when the machine was new.  This'll create a brand new admin account.  This method can be useful if you don't want to mess up any existing accounts on the machine.

Before step 4 you can use the `passwd` command to overwrite the current password for any accounts on the mac. The command `ls /Users` will show all the user names.

Comment: I had to use this method right now instead of mine, because I didn't have the Mac OS X DVD with me and it works perfectly !

Answer (score 7):

You can reboot into [single user mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1492) and change the password of a user with:

```
passwd [user]
```

Enter the new password twice and reboot.