# Deleted hash files; can't login anymore!

Tags: macos, password, permission

I've deleted the two hash files in the folder /private/var/db/shadow/hash/, corresponding to my login account. Now, I cannot login, and don't have any other account on my Mac with sudo permissions.

Is there a way in which I can reset my password? If not, will it be possible to access data belonging to this account? My other accounts do not have permissions to these folders.

Comment: can you login using single-user mode?  hold command-s on startup.

Comment: @calavera: Yes, I can login using single-user mode. Could I reset the password from there? Thanks!

Comment: @Jon: I don't know how to reset the password via command line, but if there's a way to do it via command line you should be able to do it via single-user mode.  It logs you on as root.  Maybe check `man passwd`?

Comment: @Jon: actually, check out this question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34/how-do-i-recover-the-administrator-or-root-password-on-os-x

Comment: @calavera: Thanks for your comments. I was able to reset my password following the instructions at [Reset a user's password in single user mode](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080414140636495)

Comment: @Jon: great! glad it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can boot into the terminal by holding `Command + S` at startup. You could create a new user via command line this way. [Here is a tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pdV1S6M299o). Another option is to insert the installation disc and reinstall the Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1):

*changing my comments to an answer since Jon was able to solve it using single-user mode*

Can you login using single-user mode? hold command-s on startup.

I don't know how to reset the password via command line, but if there's a way to do it via command line you should be able to do it via single-user mode. It logs you on as root. Maybe check man passwd?

Also, check out this question: [How do I recover the administrator or root password on OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34/)