# Resetting OS X Password Without Having The Installation Disc?

Tags: macos, password, login

In the event that you have forgotten the login password to your Mac (for whatever reasons). What possibilities exist to reset the password **without** having the OS X installation disc(s) ?

Comment: [This question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57119/how-can-i-get-admin-access-to-a-mac-without-knowing-the-current-password) seems to be the closest to a canonical answer we have, but also see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38921/how-do-i-reset-recover-my-superuser-password-without-the-boot-disk and [single user mode](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61905/how-can-i-reset-a-macs-password-from-single-user-mode)

Comment: @bmike Ok fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Recovery HD

The simplest way may be to use the Recovery HD.

1. Boot into the Recovery HD (hold <kbd>⌥ alt/option</kbd> at boot and select the Recovery HD).
2. Once it has booted, click **Utilities**, then **Terminal**.
3. Type `resetpassword` then <kbd>↩ enter</kbd>.
4. Follow the instructions.

### Restarting Setup Assistant

In addition to using the Recovery HD, you can also restart the Setup Assistant, create a new Administrator account, then use that account to reset the password to the original account.

You can **restart the Setup Assistant** by performing the following:

1. Boot into Single User Mode (hold <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> at boot).
2. Mount the drive by typing `/sbin/mount -uw /` then <kbd>↩ enter</kbd>.
3. Remove the Apple Setup Done file by typing `rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone` then <kbd>↩ enter</kbd>.
4. Reboot by typing `reboot` then <kbd>↩ enter</kbd>.
5. Continue setup, making sure **not** to transfer data.
6. Setup a new administrator account. You can use this account to reset the password to the original account (through System Preferences → Users & Groups).

[image]

The new account can then be deleted once the original account has been recovered.

Comment: Using the Setup Assistant worked like a charm for me, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Another option (in addition to using `resetpassword` or creating a new admin account) is to use dscl in single user mode.

1. Hold command-S on startup.
2. Run `mount -uw /`. `fsck -fy` is not needed.
3. Run `launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.opendirectoryd.plist` in 10.7 and later, or `launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.DirectoryServices.plist` in 10.6 and earlier.
4. Run `dscl . -passwd /Users/username` (where `username` is replaced with the username of the account but `-passwd` is not replaced with anything) and enter a new password. If there is an error about `com.apple.DirectoryServices.plist`, you can ignore it.
5. Run `reboot`.